# Java generate queryDSL

Tags: java, spring, jpa, querydsl

So I have a table named BLOG_REPORTERS like:

```
blog_id | reporter_id
   1          1
   2          3
```

And REPORTER:

```
reporter_id | name | etc
   1         asd    etc
```

I need to perform JOIN operation between them. I generated a QueryDSL class for them, and tried something like:

```
new JPAQuery<>(entityManager)
                .select(QReporter.reporter)
                .from(QReporter.reporter)
                .join(QBlogReporters.blogreporters)
```

but this is wrong because join() method accepts `EntityPath<P>` and QBlogReporters extends `BeanPath<T>`.

Is any way to do this?